# View not loaded when ActionResult is called from AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have called `actionresult` function from `JavaScript` using `AJAX` when a button is clicked:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.btn-SelectStudent').on('click', function () {
            $('input:radio').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var id = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("ParseSearchLists", "Upload")',
                        data: { studentId: id }
                    }).success(function (data) {
                       alert('success');
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // Or an unchecked one here...
                }
            });

            return false;
        })
    </script>
```

Inside the UploadController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ParseSearchLists(int studentId)
    {
        SearchModel searchModel = ApplicationVariables.searchResults.Where(x => x.StudentId == studentId).ToList().First();
        TempData["SearchModel"] = searchModel;
        return RedirectToAction("UploadFile", "Upload");
    }

    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        searchModel = TempData["SearchModel"] as SearchModel;
        return View(searchModel); //debug point hits here.
    }
```

Inside UploadFile(), I have returned View and it should load another view. But I get only "success" in alert but no new view is loaded. I assume, view should be loaded.

Comment: A few things.  1)  You cannot return a `RedirectToAction` in an AJAX call, the handler doesn't know what to do with that.  2)  In your `success` function for your AJAX call, you aren't doing anything with the data you received back from the server, you are simply alerting Success

Comment: So, what will be the best option in this case. i have some data in a model class, need to pass this to another page and render it.

Comment: I think on ajax success, I only get plain html or some simple strings rather than Model class.

Comment: RedirectToAction will not be called when you are calling from ajax, it better to return a json with URL where you want to redirect and in ajax request  you can use  window.location = "http://localhost:3000/Upload/UploadFile";

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are not loading view returned to div on ajax success. replace #`divname` with your div in your code in below code. i hope this helps to resolve your issue

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.btn-SelectStudent').on('click', function () {
                $('input:radio').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var id = $(this).val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ParseSearchLists", "Upload")',
                            dataType: "html",
                            data: { studentId: id }
                        }).success(function (data) {
                          $('#divName').html(data); // note replace divname with your actual divname
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        // Or an unchecked one here...
                    }
                });

                return false;
            })
        </script>
      [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ParseSearchLists(int studentId)
        {
            SearchModel searchModel = ApplicationVariables.searchResults.Where(x => x.StudentId == studentId).ToList().First();                
            return View("UploadFile",searchModel); //debug point hits here.
        }
```

Comment: I want to redirect to another view with model class.

Comment: include ViewName  in return. like   return View("ViewName", searchModel); i updated answer with your view name. i think you want to navigate to that "Uploadfile" View.hope that heps!

Answer (score 0):

You're making an "AJAX" call to the server, meaning your request is running outside of the current page request and the results will be returned to your `success` continuation routine, not to the browser's rendering engine.  Essentially the `data` parameter of that routine is probably the entire HTML response of your `UploadFile` view.

This is not what `.ajax` is used for.  It is for making asynchronous requests to the server and returning data (usually JSON or XML) to your javascript to be evaluated and displayed on the page (this is the most common use anyway).

I can't see your HTML, but wouldn't you be better off just using an `<a>` anchor (link) tag and sending your student ID on the query string?  It's hard to tell what you are attempting to do but your views' HTML (.cshtml) will never be displayed using the code you have now.